# NULLPointerException in ListView in android

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a problem in my project... i don't know how to fix it... NullPointerException

this is my MainActivity extents Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finding__bus_staion, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvBusStation);
String begin = "Tất Cả";
String finish = "Tất Cả";
    LoadListView(begin, finish);
    return view;
}
public void LoadListView(String from,String to){
    chuyendi.clear();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < chuyenXes.size() ;i++){
        chuyendi.add(chuyenXes.get(i));
    }
    if (listView!=null)
        listView=null;
    if (!(from.equals("Tất Cả"))) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < chuyenXes.size() ;i++){
            if (chuyenXes.get(i).getNoidi().equals(from)){
                chuyendi.add(chuyenXes.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    if (!(to.equals("Tất Cả"))){
        for (int i  = 0 ; i < chuyendi.size() ;i++){
            if (!(chuyendi.get(i).getNoiden().equals(to))){
                chuyendi.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    myAdapter = new BusStationAdapter(getActivity(),chuyendi);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter); //NULLPointerException in this line

}
```

can someone help me :( how to fix it?

Comment: mate why listView != null listView = null??

Comment: why `if (listView!=null)
        listView=null;` this is the reason for `listView.setAdapter(myAdapter); //NULLPointerException in this line`

Comment: because if i call the LoadListView(from,to) with new from and new to again ... it will clear the old listview and show the new listview ... i remove if (listView!=null) listView=null; and it's working but can't delete the old listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove it

```
if (listView!=null)
        listView=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

your error is due to this line

```
chuyendi.clear();
```

think in mind what if chuyendi is already empty then there is nothing to 
clear then it will through nullpointer exception

use

```
if(chuyendi.length()>0){
chuyendi.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your bellow condition because first time your listview is not null so condition is true and your list view become null. check it ok.

```
if (listView!=null)
        listView=null;
```

right is,

```
if (listView==null)
        //create again list view object.
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you do `listView = NULL`?
If `listview == null`, you can't set Adapter for `ListView`. So You should remove

```
if (listView!=null)
    listView=null;
```

Comment: because if i call the LoadListView(from,to) with new from and new to again ... it will clear the old listview and show the new listview ...
i remove  if (listView!=null) listView=null; and it's working but can't delete the old listview.

Comment: Clear the old listview? You can use notifyDataSetChanged of adater to refresh data.